# Embedding swf with frame labels and controlling it in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, flash, embed

I'm trying to embed swf file with some frame labels defined in its timeline into my Flex application:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="absolute" width="1000" height="563" creationComplete="doSomething()">

    <mx:Script>
        <![CDATA[

            private var movieClip:MovieClip;

            private function doSomething():void {
                movieClip = swfFile.content as MovieClip;
                movieClip.gotoAndPlay('playIntro');
                movieClip.addEventListener("swfFinished", doSomethingElse);
            }

            private function doSomethingElse():void {
                //
            }

        ]]>
    </mx:Script>

    <mx:SWFLoader id="swfFile" width="1000" height="563" source="@Embed(source='test.swf')" /> 

</mx:Application>
```

However, I cannot control swf timeline in this way... Is it possible to embed swf file and control it in a way I want?

Thanks!

Comment: What happens when you do this? Does the complete event fire? If it does is the movieclip null?

Comment: Hm, yes, seems that complete event does not fire at all :-/ I tried to put `creationComplete` in `Application` class and after that `movieClip` is not null. However, it still won't play movie from labeled frame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some searches on this seem to indicate that this is happens when the swf is embedded. If you can get away with not embedding the swf, do that.

Here's a solution I found that allows the embed to work:
http://iamjosh.wordpress.com/2008/04/09/embedding-flash-in-flex/

I *think* the issue may lie Flash Player's security model, just a hunch. It may not be allowing this type of communication with the embedded swf ... but you might be able to do something like `Security.allowDomain("*")` (a dangerous shortcut).

But first, check out the docs for [allowDomain](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/Security.html#allowDomain%28%29), as the docs suggest you might be able to do this:

```
Security.allowDomain(loader.contentLoaderInfo.url); // 'loader' is a SwfLoader
```

But I'm guessing that `url` might be null in the embed case :)